# Account for depth and height of text with tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox, height

I want to make a "blocks" of words, and I want the to have the same vertical size and alignment.

But when I do:

```
\newtcbox{\tag}{nobeforeafter, box align=base,size=small}
\tag{Photo} \tag{may}
```

I get:

[image]

Because the box uses the real text height. Is there some kind of "line-height" property as in CSS that can be used for the height of the

Comment: box-align=base is suspect

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can insert a \strut:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\newtcbox{\tag}{nobeforeafter, box align=base,size=small,before upper=\strut}
\tag{Photo} \tag{may}


\end{document}
```

[image]